# Type 'Type1 | Type2' is not asignable to type 'Type1'

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Hello I have these types definition

```
export interface ICubeParams{
  width:number,
  depth:number,
  height:number,
  color?:string
}

export interface ISphereParams{
  radius:number
  color?:string
}
```

and a variable of type:

```
let parameters: ICubeParams | ISphereParams
```

Then, in another class Cube I pass parameters to the constructor (in this case parameters is of type ICubeParams)

```
const params: ICubeParams = this.parameters;
```

But I get the following error

```
Type 'ICubeParams | ISphereParams' is not assignable to type 'ICubeParams'.
```

Any clue of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `params` needs to be `ICubeParams` and `parameters` might be something else, thats why it is a mismatch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`parameters` can be either `ICubeParams` or `ISphereParams`. When you assign it to `params` which must be of type `ICubeParams`, the typescript compiler complains it can't validate that the assignment is valid. Maybe `parameters` is a `ISphereParams` and you are assigning it to `params`.

You can use a type assertion if you are sure `parameters` will not be a `ISphereParams` when that assignment occurs:

```
const params = this.parameters as ICubeParams ;
```

Or you can use a type guard to ensure the assignment is valid (and let typescript know about the fact that you performed the check):

```
let parameters: ICubeParams | ISphereParams

//in type guard
if ('width' in parameters) {
    const params: ICubeParams = parameters;
} else { 
    /* Now what ? Handle unexpected case or ignore it, up to you */ 
}
```

Comment: Nice one. Can `instanceof` be used as a type guard in this context? Property `width` might change or be removed over time, if `instanceof` can be used, would it be a better type guard choice?

Comment: @MehmetSeckin No. `instanceof` can be used as a type guard with classes. Interfaces are erased and do not exist at runtime, the javascript `instanceof` operator would need a class to work.